# Error TypeError: login_submit() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python, bottle

I have made a simple program using Bottle framework. I am getting this error:

> 'TypeError: login_submit() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)'

The code is:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import codecs
from bottle import route, run, template


@route('/login')
def login_form():
    return '''<form method="POST" action="/login">
            <input name="name" type="text" />
            <input name="password" type="password" />
            <input type="submit" />
          </form>'''

@route('/login', method='POST')
def login_submit(request):
  name = request.forms.get('name')
  password = request.forms.get('password')
  if check_login(name, password):
    return "<p>Your login was correct</p>"
  else:
    return "<p>Login failed</p>"

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the docs](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html), you import request, rather than having it as an argument:

```
from bottle import post, request

...

@route('/login', method='POST') # or @post('/login')
def login_submit():
  name = request.forms.get('name')
  password = request.forms.get('password')
  if check_login(name, password):
    return "<p>Your login was correct</p>"
  else:
    return "<p>Login failed</p>"
```

Comment: Right answer, but if you are going to show a solution importing `get` and `post` it would probably be helpful to show how those can be used as decorators.